# Should I include lightweight in my workout if I have an endurance based goal?

Tags: push-ups, endurance, calisthenics, goals

So I have goals involving bulking and getting stronger(increasing my bench, squat, curl, etc.), but recently I have put into action a goal to do 100 push ups in a row. Will lifting lighter weights help me get to this goal faster? And if won't interfere with my bulking in the process?

Answer (score 1):

#### Getting to 100 push ups

I don't believe that lighter weights will help you achieve your 100 push up goals; [here's a good program](http://hundredpushups.com/) that can increase your numbers.

There are also certain exercises that might increase your push up endurance; essentially, performing ***more reps*** of tricep-based and shoulder-based exercises *(dips, pull ups, bench press of a weight close yours)* should assist in your endurance.

#### Will It Interfere With Your Bulking?

It shouldn't; while it's cardio-based, the exercise shouldn't burn enough calories to interfere with your bulking phase. Also, if you stick with it long enough, your body will naturally adapt, which will reduce the calorie impact.

#### Will It Impact Other Exercises?

This depends on the exercise. I expect your bench press numbers to remain stagnant or reduce while your body's adapting to the exercise. There might be an impact to your curls; there shouldn't be an impact to your squat. Essentially, your tricep and chest exercises should be affected due to the fatigue in your arms.

Of course, you might be able to structure your training so it has little impact on your other exercises; however, I don't think this is avoidable.

***Just be realistic about your expectations and make adjustments as needed.***

Good luck!

Comment: I'm curious how it would affect bicep curls.

Comment: @DaveNewton While your body is getting adjusted to that much reps, your arms should naturally be sore, which will affect affect how much load you can put on them. I'd say it depends on your body, your mind and how much your working weight is.

Comment: Hrm. Never noticed any major issues with that, with myself or with clients, but maybe we were all just lucky.

Comment: Hmmm.......do you or your clients perform 100 pushup reps without rest? Also, how much curl weights are we talking about? Curling with 20 lb dumbbells might not be noticecable than curling with 60 lb dumbbells.

Comment: OP is starting a *progression* to do 100 pushups. I doubt I could now, but yes, I did, and several of my past clients could as well. Not really relevant, though; my point was that I don't see how pushups are going to have a significant impact on curls. Lifters regularly train different bodyparts on different days and not once have I heard anyone say "I can't curl today, I did chest yesterday." YMMV.

Comment: I guess it would depend on the individual. But anecdotally, the endurance required to perform 100 pushups *(or more importantly, while training to be able to perform 100 pushups)* would have an impact on the curl numbers if one lifts heavy. I've had similar experiences with chin ups too. *(Of course, the programs I used required the exercises to be performed daily....or at least 3 days a week);* so, that could play an impact. In any case, the last sentence sums it best: ***be realistic and make adjustments.***